# python speed up text parsing

Tags: python, parsing, text

I wrote function for text file parsing with Python, avoiding using RegEx expression for speed.  The code will split line at comma and space, trim and strip spaces and empty lines.  The code first replace all spaces with commas, then split them at all commas, remove all empty strings, finally delete empty lines.  The process make the parsing slower.  I want to make it more faster.

list(map(str.strip, line.split(','))) is I think it is best for spliting text line at commas.  Thing is this does not handle spaces and multiple commas.  My choice is add more code to handle spaces and empty strings, and empty lines, which make the time slower.

this is how I wrote:

```
def text_extractor(infile):
    output = []
    for line in infile:
        # handle spaces
        line1 = ','.join(line.split())
        # handle commas
        line2 = list(map(str.strip, line1.split(',')))
        # remove empty strings from list
        line3 = [x for x in line2 if x]
        # skip empty line
        if line3 != []:
            output.append(line3)
    return output

def text_writer(input, outfile):
    for line in input:
        outfile.write(' '.join(line)+'\n')

with open('./test.dat','rt') as infile, open('./test.out','wt') as outfile:
    output = text_extractor(infile)
    text_writer(output,outfile)

'''
(input)
*HEADER, ./test/test.inp
1, 2, 3, 4,,,

a b c d e f ,

(output)
[["*HEADER", "./test/test.inp"],
 ["1","2","3","4"],
 ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]]
'''
```

Comment: Why do you think regex will be slow? I would try `re.findall("[^ ,]+", line)`

Comment: Regular expressions are usually faster for such a job. Replacing whitespaces by comma and removing empty entries can be done rather quickly with one or two regexes applied to the whole `infile` at once.

Comment: Although your code may not be optimal, unless your input file is massive this should run very quickly. What timings are you getting and what is your target?

Comment: @Joe `re.findall("[^ ,]+", line)` always returne \n at the end of line.  if we can avoid that, this should be good.

Comment: Try `output = [re.findall(r'[^ ,]+', line.rstrip()) for line in f if line.rstrip()]`